# Notation for the product of corresponding elements of two matrices

Tags: matrices, notation

I'm not sure how to describe the multiplication of off-diagonal elements of a (co)variance matrix (covariances) with corresponding elements of it's correlation matrix, in a succinct way.

In full, I want to describe the multiplication of elements of a correlation matrix with the square root of the corresponding elements of the covariance matrix. But it is specifying the corresponding elements of the respective matrices that I'm struggling with.

How can I describe this with correct notation?

Thanks

Comment: you mean, the Hadamard product? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A, B\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ are given then write
$$A\circ B$$
for their entrywise product: the  entry at $(i,j)$ of $A\circ B$ is $\,a_{ij}b_{ij}\,$. This is called the *Schur product of $A$ and $B$*. And also: the *Hadamard product*.

It has the important property that $A\circ B\,$ is a positive matrix if $A$ and $B$ are positive.

You have commutativity $B\circ A = A\circ B$, in sharp contrast to matrix multiplication.

It may conveniently be applied to select or weight individual entries, which is your aim.
Consider the example
$$\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\  0&0&1}\:\circ\: \pmatrix{j&e&s\\m&a&th\\j&o&y}
\;=\; \pmatrix{j&0&0\\0&a&0\\0&0&y}$$
selecting the diagonal entries.

Comment: That's great thanks. Can you please confirm if this notation specifies to only give the product of the off-diagonal elements? If not, how best can that be included?

Comment: Let $I$ be the identity matrix and $J$ the _all-ones_ matrix. Then the desired product of the covariance $C$ and correlation $R$ is 
$\;R\circ\Big((J-I)\circ C\Big)^{1/2}\;$

Comment: @greg thanks for this. Does it only specify that I want the off diagonal elements of the matrix from this process? For example, If I have already specified the derivation of the diagonal elements.

Comment: Yes. For example, for $n=3,$ notice that $$(J-I) = \pmatrix{0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0}$$
Therefore the Hadamard product of _any_ $\,3\times 3\,$ matrix with $(J-I)$ will zero-out its diagonal terms while leaving the off-diagonal terms unchanged.

Comment: You may use one of the factors like a switch for the other one to pick an entry, or to nullify it.