# Matrix Multiplication Defined Differently

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I've been recently diving into some linear algebra and, as we all know, to add two matrices, corresponding parts are added. But this is *not* the case with matrix multiplication. The conventional notion of matrix multiplication involves taking a sum of products of the "corresponding" parts along the $i^{th}$ row of the left matrix with the $i^{th}$ column of the right matrix. But I was wondering if there was any use to defining matrix multiplication in the same way that matrix addition is defined.

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices where

> $\begin{equation*}
> A = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
> a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n}\\
> a_{21} & \dots & \dots & a_{2n} \\
> \vdots & & & \vdots \\
> a_{n1} & \dots & \dots & a_{nn}
> \end{bmatrix}
> \end{equation*}$ and $\begin{equation*}
> B = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
> b_{11} & b_{12} & \dots & b_{1n}\\
> b_{21} & \dots & \dots & b_{2n} \\
> \vdots & & & \vdots \\
> b_{n1} & \dots & \dots & b_{nn}
> \end{bmatrix}
> \end{equation*}$

> Suppose that instead of the conventional matrix product $AB$ that we're all familiar with, the product $AB$ was defined to be:

> $\begin{equation*}
> AB = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
> a_{11}b_{11} & a_{12}b_{12} & \dots & a_{1n}b_{1n}\\
> a_{21}b_{21} & \dots & \dots & a_{2n}b_{2n} \\
> \vdots & & & \vdots \\
> a_{n1}b_{n1} & \dots & \dots & a_{nn}b_{nn}
> \end{bmatrix}
> \end{equation*}$

Is there any usefulness for a multiplication operation to be defined in such a way? I'm sure I could find an explanation for why matrix multiplication is defined the way that it regularly is, but is there a branch of linear algebra that uses the operation that I have proposed?

Comment: the operation you are describing is known as the hadamard product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)

Comment: Or synonymously, the *Schur product* of two matrices having the same shape.
See [also here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4110257/316749) .
Also notice that it equals a submatrix of the tensor product $A\otimes B$.

Comment: You see this multiplication used a lot in Matlab. Normal matrix multiplication arises naturally when you want to compose two geometric transformations. For example, a 2D rotation is implemented by a $2\times 2$ matrix and composing two rotations is itself a single rotation, given by the matrix product of the two individual ones.